# How to avoid wrong placement of HTML tags caused by indentation in a Slim template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have the following slim code in a Rails view:

```
- @collection_tags.each do |c|
    .cell.small-9.medium-4.large-3
      = content_tag :h2, c.name
      .brands-list
        - first_letter = nil
        - @brands.each do |brand|
          - if brand.page.tags.where(group_id: APP_CONFIG[:collection_tags_group_id] || 2).first.id == c.id
            - if brand.short_title.first.upcase != first_letter
              - first_letter = brand.short_title.first.upcase
              .letter-block
                .letter
                  = first_letter
                ul.menu.vertical
                  li
                    = link_to brand.short_title.capitalize, '#'
            - else
              li
                = link_to brand.short_title.capitalize, '#'
```

[Here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIXV5.jpg). The last two items should be placed inside the last block as the letter is still the same but I can't figure out how to do it since Slim closes HTML tags based on indentation.

Any way to make it work in Slim or should I just go back to ERB for this particular view?

Comment: Did you try https://html2slim.herokuapp.com/ ?

Comment: I wasn't trying to convert an HTML view to a Slim one. I was iterating over @brands (list of hashes) and if the first letter of the short_title value is different from the previous one I was creating a new letter block. Otherwise, I wanted to print it inside the same block as the previous one.

I ended up changing the structure of the variable to avoid this issue but if I was getting that data from an external API, it would still be an issue.

Comment: I mean if your html works like it should without slim and you think that it's in slim your difficulty, just convert it though this converter and check where is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your output, it seems like `slim` is doing the right thing.  Try indenting the second `li` lines to match the level of indentation of the `li` in the `then` portion of the if. That should fix your problem.